# Filter money column by digits after comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such table in my db. 'Payment' column is in "money" format.

| ID | Payment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 41.20 |
| 2 | 42.30 |
| 3 | 43.4032 |
| 4 | 44.50 |
| 5 | 45.6082 |
| 6 | 46.70411 |

How can I filter money column by values that have more than 2 digits after dot?

Was thinking about cursor and some sort of casting to string but the actual table has thousands of records and this method would be too slow. The result table should be like this

| ID | Payment |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 43.4032 |
| 5 | 45.6082 |
| 6 | 46.70411 |

Comment: Please do not use images - use the formatted text you started with - which I have reverted for you.

Comment: Don't think of money values as strings, they're just numbers. So, use mathematics...

Comment: I'd probably use `WHERE payment <> ROUND(payment,2)`

Comment: what is the data type for `Payment`?

Comment: @Squirrel - The question states [`money`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: It stated `"money" format`. data type `money` have 4 decimal places.  but `46.70411` is 5 decimal places

Comment: Hmm, It did say "money typed column" until the final edit.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Maybe `WHERE (payment * 1000) % 10 > 0`

Comment: Thank you all for you help. Apprceiate it. Will take in notice comment for how to compose posts in better way :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an option using modulus

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Payment] money)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,41.20)
,(2,42.30)
,(3,43.4032)
,(4,44.50)
,(5,45.6082)
,(6,46.70411)


Select *
 From  @YourTable
 Where payment  % 0.01 <> 0
```

**Results**

```
ID  Payment
3   43.4032
5   45.6082
6   46.7041
```